Can gradio functions return components
I want to use gradio to create a dropdown to choose a task id and fetch the json under that id and display it as custom component implemented under a block
An example of how this may work is something like this:
# load tsh function
def load_content(task_id: str):
  # read tsh
  dao = FileStorageAccessObject(id=task_id)
  tsh = dao.read(identifier='tsh')

  # render
  # custom component
  with gr.Blocks() as block:
    for (key, value) in tsh.items():
      with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
          gr.Textbox(value=key)
        with gr.Column():
          gr.Textbox(value=value)
        with gr.Column():
          gr.Checkbox(label='Accept', value=False)

  # return
  return block


# interface
with gr.Blocks() as los_generation_iface:
  gr.Markdown("## Generate Learning Objectives")

  with gr.Column():
    task_id_dropdown = gr.Dropdown(label='Choose Content', choices=os.listdir(path=env.STORAGE_PATH))
    content_layout = gr.Blocks()

  task_id_dropdown.change(fn=load_content, inputs=[task_id_dropdown], outputs=[content_layout])


# launch
los_generation_iface.launch()

How can this behavior be achieved?

What works and what does not? Please add a screenshot or screencast that shows your current GUI-behavior. It's easier to try a simple [example] with print or Textbox like here instead of dao-functions we don't have.

first run code to see if it works. And if gives error messages then show error in question (not in comments)

Figured out a solution from the documentation. The trick is using the @gr.render decorator:
# interface
with gr.Blocks() as los_generation_iface:
  gr.Markdown("## Generate Learning Objectives")

  with gr.Column():
    task_id_dropdown = gr.Dropdown(label='Choose Content', choices=os.listdir(path=env.STORAGE_PATH))

  # load content
  @gr.render(inputs=[task_id_dropdown])
  def load_content(task_id: str):
    # error handling
    if task_id is None:
      return

    # read tsh
    dao = FileStorageAccessObject(id=task_id)
    tsh = dao.read(identifier='tsh')

    # custom component
    with gr.Blocks() as block:
      for (key, value) in tsh.items():
        with gr.Row():
          with gr.Column():
            gr.Textbox(value=key)
          with gr.Column():
            gr.Textbox(value=value)
          with gr.Column():
            gr.Checkbox(label='Accept', value=False)

